# Existence of Matrix inverses depending on the existence of the inverse of the others..

Tags: matrices

Let $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n\times m}$ be two matrices with real entries. Prove that $I-AB$ is invertible iff $I-BA$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$(I-BA)^{-1}=X$ (say), Now expand left side. we get $$X=I+BA+ (BA)(BA)+(BA)(BA)(BA)+\dots$$ $$AXB=AB+(AB)^2+(AB)^3+(AB)^4+\dots$$  $$I+AXB=I+(AB)+(AB)^2+\dots+(AB)^n+\dots=(I-AB)^{-1}$$

Check yourself: $(I+AXB)(I-AB)=I$, $(I-AB)(I+AXB)=I$

Comment: You're writing a series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (AB)^{i}$, but this in general *won't converge*.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the fact that $\det(I - AB) = \det(I - BA)$; this is called the [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem). A neat explanation is given at the beginning of [this beautiful blog post by Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/).

Actually, this is a results that holds in any ring with $1$, I first discovered it in an exercise in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*.

Here's a proof that in any ring $A$ with $1$, we have that $1-ab$ is invertible if and only if $1-ba$ is. Assume $1-ab$ invertible. Compute
$$
ba 
= 
b (1-ab)(1-ab)^{-1} a
=
(b-bab)(1-ab)^{-1} a
=
(1 - ba) b (1-ab)^{-1} a.
$$
Thus
$$
1 - ba = 1 - (1 - ba) b (1-ab)^{-1} a.
$$
Taking the second term on the RHS to the LHS,
$$
(1-ba) \cdot (1 + b(1-ab)^{-1} a) = 1.
$$
Of course one has to check that  $(1 + b(1-ab)^{-1} a) \cdot (1-ba) = 1$ also holds, and then one has $$(1-ba)^{-1} = 1 + b(1-ab)^{-1} a.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume $m<n$, use the fact that $p_{BA}(t)=t^{n-m}p_{AB}(t)$, where $p_{AB}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $AB$. Similar for $m>n$.